# Why do we use complements to perform subtraction operation in computer systems?

Tags: twos-complement, digital-logic, ones-complement

Why do we have to use **complements** (e.g 2's complement, 10's complement etc) in computer systems to perform subtraction operations? Just like circuits for addition operations(adders) , we do have circuits for subtraction(subtractors), right?

Comment: We don't **have to**. It is just a more convenient representation than the alternative

Comment: No need for separate "subtractors" when you can just use an adder for both addition and subtraction.

Comment: Thanks for your responses guys :)

Answer (score 0):

The logical answer for your question is, that if we can solve a problem just by using operations(adder) then why make your circuit complex using adder and subtracts.
Making it more simple using multiple adder in circuit is easier has compared to adder and subtracts.
For more information you can see the images below and think if we have to join multiple of them how complex our circuit will become;
[Simple adder circuit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlJoI.jpg)
[Simple Subtractor circuit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vP08y.jpg)